# Not able to fetch json object array in Handlebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, handlebars.js

Hi I am new to handlebar and rails ,I am trying to render a handlebar template which consumes a json object having 2 values something like this

**json Object is having list array object as string which is why i am not able to fetch its value in handlebar template as show below code**

```
Object {type: "followers", list: "[{"user_id":33,"user_name":"rajesh","first_name":"avatars/000/000/033/dummyavatar.png?1421501369"}]"}
```

**handlebar template**

```
{{#compare this.type '==' 'followers'}}
{{#each this.list}}
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 project-box">
    <div class="col-md-8 align-center">
      <a href="/project/{{profile_url}}" class="avatar-md">
        <img src="{{image_url}}" class="avatar-md">
      </a>
      <span>
      {{user_name}}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 clearfix action">
      <a href="/project/{{project_url}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
        follow
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

{{/compare}}

**controller**

```
def getFollowersList
    objFollowNetwork = FollowNetwork.new(session[:user_id])
    @listOfFollowers = objFollowNetwork.getListOfFollowers
    #@listOfFollowers[0].image_urlA
    objHash = Hash.new
    objHash['type'] = 'followers'
    objHash['list'] = @listOfFollowers.to_json(:methods => :image_url) 
    render :json => objHash
    # render :json => @model.to_json(:only => [:id,:name,:homephone,:cellphone], :methods => [:avatar_url])
  end
```

**Ajax call function**

```
    function getFollowerList() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/getFollowers",
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success :function(result){
      debugger;
      context = JSON.parse(result);
      followerList = Handlebars.templates['followersCommonTemplate'](result);
      $('#followers-sections').html(followerList);
    }
  });
}
```

is there any way to fetch list object array in handlebar ?

Comment: So passing the list in an Obj isntead of an Array would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this i tried making list array to json object and assigining that to result.list .

```
result.list = JSON.parse(result.list)
followerList = Handlebars.templates['followersCommonTemplate'](result);
```

this will create an json object having list as array object!